# iOS App Rejection due to private API call viewControllerForView:, Facebook API

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, appstore-approval

My app was rejected because

> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

in the method

> viewControllerForView:

I asked where I used viewControllerForView: and they responded

> “viewControllerForView:” was found in the methods: 
>   -[FBSDKLikeButton _handleTap:] and -[FBSDKLikeButton _like:].

My FBSDKLoginKit, FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKCoreKit pods are all at 4.15.1 (the latest version). How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t need to make any changes in your code, read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242477629268301/) post from Facebook developers of how to solve it.

> After integrating our SDK into your iOS app, you will need to submit
>   your app to Apple for review. As part of this review process, you will
>   be asked if your app uses the Advertising Identifier (IDFA). Please
>   check "Yes". You will then be asked how your app makes use of it. The
>   question will take this form: This app uses the Advertising Identifier
>   to (select all that apply)?
>   - Serve advertisements within the app
>   - Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement
>   - Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement
>
> If you will be using the Audience Network framework, you must select
>   the first option.  If you are using our core framework to track
>   install attribution and app events, please select the second and third
>   options.  If you are using both, select all three.
>
> You will also be asked to check a box to confirm that your app honors
>   a user's Limit Ad Tracking setting in iOS. The Facebook SDK honors the
>   iOS Limited Ad Tracking Setting. When a person enables Limited Ad
>   Tracking, Facebook only uses data obtained through the use of the
>   Advertising Identifier for “Limited Advertising Purposes” as defined
>   by the iOS Developer Program License Agreement. Please make sure check
>   this box when prompted.
>
> Marking these questions in this way will help ensure a smooth review
>   process